ASP.NET Core: URL rewriting does not work with a static file
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect("login", "login.html")); //works
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("login", "login.html", false)); //doesnt work

In the second case i get error 404, page not found. Why?
The file is in the wwwroot directory.

Be sure call app.UseRewriter before app.UseStaticFiles(), otherwise  the RewriteMiddleware might be superseeded by the one in charge of the static files, which could mess up your rewrite rules:
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("login", "login.html", false)); 
app.UseStaticFiles();

